# Show this element is in the center of the group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Consider the group ring $R = (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})S_3$ . Show that the element $\gamma = \bar{2}(1 2) + \bar{2}(13) + \bar{2}(2 3)$ is in the center of the ring.

The ring has $5^6$ elements, so I can't really go through and and prove that $x\gamma = \gamma x$  $\forall x \in R$. I can see that $\bar{2}$ is in the center of $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})$ but the individual elements (12), (13), and (23) aren't in the center of $S_3$. How can I prove this?

Edit: Can I assume that an element in the center of $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})$ multiplied by an element in the center of $S_3$ is an element in the center of R?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** It's enough to prove it only for a set of generators of $S_3$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this. Are you implying that (12) + (13) + (23) would be the center of $S_3$ and it would help to represent $S_3$ by a set of generators?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I mean that all elements of $R$ can be expressed by generators of $S_3$. If all generators commute with $\gamma$, then every group element and every group algebra element will do so.

Comment: Can I assume that an element in the center of (ℤ/5ℤ) multiplied by an element in the center of S3 is an element in the center of R?

Comment: Well, the ring $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$ is commutative. But yes. You can also prove it, not just assume :)